# Pandas contains() returning an empty series while searching for text in a DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Dataset: [`fandango_score_comparison.csv`](http://github.com/mircealex/Movie_ratings_2016_17/raw/master/fandango_score_comparison.csv)

I'm trying to access a row that matches a given movie name using the following code:

```py
df = pd.read_csv("http://github.com/mircealex/Movie_ratings_2016_17/raw/master/fandango_score_comparison.csv")

df.drop_duplicates(subset=["FILM"], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)

movie_name = df.FILM.iloc[0]
movie_df = df[df["FILM"].str.contains(movie_name)]
```

But the `movie_df` I get is always empty, irrespective of the `movie_name` I select. What am I missing or doing wrongly?

Comment: Try `df[df["FILM"].str.contains(movie_name), regex=False]`. contains assumes the argument is a regular expression. Your first movie name may accidentally be a valid regex.

Comment: You probably meant `df[df["FILM"].str.contains(movie_name, regex=False)]`.

Comment: Thanks, it's resolved with 'regex' parameter in contains().

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, and [as documented here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html#pandas.Series.str.contains), `pandas.Series.str.contains()` takes a `regex=` parameter, which by default is `True`. This means that if your `movie_name` contains special regular-expression characters (such as `*`, `()`, `[]`, and so on), it will be interpreted as a regular expression, which is most likely what is happening.

You should be ok if you explicitly disable regular expressions:

```py
movie_df = df[df["FILM"].str.contains(movie_name, regex=False)]
```